# How to get a more detailed x-axis when plotting a tsibble?

Tags: r, plot, time, time-series, tsibble

I am currently following along with *Forecasting: Principles and Practice*, 3rd Edition, which is graciously available [online](https://otexts.com/fpp3/). To replicate my issue, you will need to install and then load the package `fpp3`. You will then need to carry out the following in R (or RStudio):

```r
PBS %>%
  filter(ATC2 == "A10") %>%
  select(Month, Concession, Type, Cost) %>%
  summarise(TotalC = sum(Cost)) %>%
  mutate(Cost = TotalC / 1e6) -> a10
```

After defining `a10`, it will then be necessary to plot the `tsibble`, like so:

```r
autoplot(a10, Cost) +
  labs(y = "$ (millions)",
       title = "Australian antidiabetic drug sales")
```

You should then get a plot like this:

[image: tsibble plot with somewhat faulty x-axis]

It's fine for the most part, but I would like to have at least twice as many ticks on the x-axis, possibly more if they can be rotated by 45° or so. I tried something that seemed promising which was adding `scale_x_date(date_labels = "%m-%Y")` to the plot object but that only works with objects of class `Date` and here we are dealing with `yearmonth`s. How can I get a more detailed x-axis under these circumstances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be changing the class of `Month` to class date and applying `scale_x_date()`:

```
a10 %>% 
  mutate(Month = as.Date(Month)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Month, y=Cost)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year")
```

[image]

Comment: You're a literal hero

Answer (score 6):

You can change the x axis scale for a `yearmonth()` using `scale_x_yearmonth()`. This also applies to other date types like `yearquarter()` and `yearweek()`.

```r
library(fpp3)
PBS %>%
  filter(ATC2 == "A10") %>%
  select(Month, Concession, Type, Cost) %>%
  summarise(TotalC = sum(Cost)) %>%
  mutate(Cost = TotalC / 1e6) -> a10

autoplot(a10, Cost) +
  labs(y = "$ (millions)",
       title = "Australian antidiabetic drug sales") + 
  scale_x_yearmonth(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>